# How to solve selinux haproxy connection with puppet?

Tags: puppet, haproxy, selinux

I have an issue with haproxy in puppet. I can solve it by settig *haproxy_connet_any* to true, but I don't want to open it to *any* ports, rather open it for a specific port. Any ideas?

I have tried to add the port to selinux type *http_port_t*, which is a way to open a specific port (*semange port -a -p tcp -t http_port_t 8041*), but I couldn't make it to work in puppet. Can anyone help?

```
selinux::port { 'http_port_t':
  ensure => 'ensure',
  seltype => 'http_port_t',
  protocol => 'tcp',
  port => '8041',
}
```

[SOLVED] The code works, you only need to add an argument for semanage port, -a for add or -m for modify, etc.

Comment: Since you figured out how to do this, you should write up a proper answer to the question yourself, and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to fix this problem is to add "argument => -m" for modify or "argument => -a" for add.

```
selinux::port { 'Allow port 8041':
    ensure => 'ensure',
    seltype => 'http_port_t',
    protocol => 'tcp',
    port => '8041',
    argument => '-a',
}
```